# Compiling and running java program from command prompt (It runs in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

first of all, let me tell you that this is my first attempt to write some code with Java so, if my question is a bit silly sorry about that.

In windows,I've used Eclipse as an IDE and my project just compiles and run fine if I click the run button of eclipse. However when I've tried to compile and run my program through command prompt I got lots of errors. These are mainly :

```
error: package Jama does not exist
import Jama.SingularValueDecomposition;

error: cannot find symbol
       Sequence seq1=new Sequence(pdbFileName1); 

error: cannot find symbol
       ParsePDB parser=new ParsePDB();

error: cannot find symbol
       DynamicTable dt= new DynamicTable();
```

I got all of these except the first one multiple times but for the clearity, I've copied them only one time.

Now, I want to show my project directory,

```
Workspace
    Project1
        .settings
         bin
         src
            Jama // this is another folder which I've found on the web and used it in my project 
            com
               src
                 assg1 // these 4 files are under com.src.assg1 package name
                    assg1.java // this one includes my main function
                    DynamicTable.java
                    ParsePDB.java
                    Sequence.java                    
         .classpath
         .project
```

Now, first I have typed `cd workspace/Project1/src/com/src/assg1` and then type `javac assg1.java` and as a result I've got the errors that I mentioned above. Now does anyone who knows what is my problem ?

Comment: i think 'Jama' should be in your source 'src' folder or part of the java classpath

Comment: @user3214281 as you say, I moved it into src folder and type javac assg1.java but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile your source from its root source directory. The relative path to your .java file should be the same as its fully qualified name:

```
cd workspace/Project1/src/
javac com/src/assg1/assg1.java
```

To run it (from the same directory):

```
java com.src.assg1.assg1
```

If you want to emulate what eclipse is doing - separate directory for source and generated classes:

```
cd workspace/Project1/
javac -sourcepath src -d bin src/com/src/assg1/assg1.java
java -cp bin com.src.assg1.assg1
```

Comment: yeap its work, thank you, and one more question. Now, what should I do in order to run this compiled code ? I mean in c++ I was typing ./a.out what is the equalivent of this command in java ?

Comment: again thank you it also works, but lead me to new problem. I know it looks like I've asked my question part by part but It has just came up. Now in this project I read some txt files and I put them under workspace/Project1 folder. However, code could not find it now, where should I put them ? Under the same directory with assg1.java ? @Banthar

Comment: putting src in where ? In my assg1.java class, I give the name of file like String fname="readThisFile.txt" should I change it to fname="src/readThisFile.txt" ?

Comment: In first case `src/` is your working directory. You have to put all your files there or update paths to `"../readThisFile.txt"`. If you use the second option `Project1/` is your working directory (like when launching from eclipse) and no changes are necessary.